# How much is known about the Old Republic's era by the time period the movies are set in

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Does at least some information about Revan and Malak, the Jedi Civil War (or maybe even the Rakatans or the original Sith species) survive to the time period the movies are set in?

Even if not public knowledge, is there any indication of at least the Clone War era Jedi council to know about those historical events, even if only in form of legends?

If not even the faintest hints can be found in canon, is there something in Legends?

Comment: Considering the far-past Old Republic setting was considered for the Revan story explicitly so that it could be pulled off without connecting it heavily to the movies... I don't think it's very likely.  Events in that timeframe (Coruscant was sacked and the Temple destroyed) leave it less likely.  The Rakatan were already lost legends at that point.  I think some Canon Welding was done in Legends level canon, but I'm not familiar with details.

Comment: The [Rakata are mentioned in the Legends novel *Darth Plagueis*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rakata#Appearances) (Revan as well) so the Sith knew of the events. They also appear in a few other novels dealing with the same era, but I don't have those novels so I'm not sure if the public or the Jedi knew of them. Revan, Malak, the Jedi Civil War, the Rakatans, etc. are strictly Legends so they don't appear in canon at all.

Comment: Rakata Prime is in canon now though

Comment: It would be impossible for there to be canon indication of knowledge of those events (before the Disney purchase/takeover), seeing as the first Star Wars: KotOR game was published in 2003, and the second one was published in 2004. I am not even sure Disney considers the Old Republic-era stuff canon anymore, so it is unlikely.

Comment: @DarthVader : yes, but part of the prequel trilogy was made after the games. Also, there were animated series etc. about the clone war.

Comment: @vsz well, then. I certainly need to check the publishing dates for them then, since I always thought the prequels were made in the 90s.

Comment: @vsz I now see that episode III was published 2 years after KotOR 1 and 1 year after KotOR 2

Comment: Holocrons (Both Jedi and Sith) are the main source of this type of information that you see. Both in LEgends and Canon Holocrons of knowledge that speak of characters from KOTR (though mainly talking about ancient sith here) and before are found and learned from by various people. We can even go into Exar Kun's spirit residing on Yavin 4 as a link to the ancient sith teachings and events also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In Legends

It appears that there was very little public knowledge of ancient history. In the Clone Wars novel *Wild Space*, Bail Organa has never heard of the Sith, and Padmé only knows because of what she's overheard from the Jedi:

> "Padmé," he said, and swung about to face her. "Have you ever heard of the Sith?"
>
> [...]
>
> So with only the smallest twinge of conscience, she looked at Bail Organa and lied to him a second time. "Sith? No. Why? Who—what—are they?"
>
> "I don't know," he said, frustrated. "Until this morning I'd never heard of them, either."
>
> —*The Clone Wars: Wild Space* (2008)

Since senators would likely know more about Republic history than other citizens, and they didn't know despite the Sith having been the Republic's adversary for almost every major war in the past 5,000 years at that point, it's probable that the average citizen hadn't heard of them either.

However, Revan and Malak were apparently known to con man Dozer Creed shortly after the Battle of Yavin:

> "No," Han said firmly before anyone else could voice an opinion. "If they get loose, they'll be coming back here. We stay."
>
> "If they get loose?" Dozer retorted. "Don't be ridiculous. Who do you think they are, Revan and Malak? I'm telling you, they’re hammer squash. And so are we if we stay here."
>
> —*Scoundrels* (2013)

Plagueis and Palpatine appeared to know about Revan and Malak as well. They were mentioned in Palpatine's [Book of Sith](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Book_of_Sith), and Plagueis had this to say about his prostheses around 32 BBY:

> "Your thoughts betray you," Plagueis said. "Do you think that Malak's powers were weakened by Revan's lightsaber? Bane by being encrusted in orbalisks? Do you think Gravid's young apprentice was hindered by the prosthesis she was forced to wear after fighting him?"
>
> —*Darth Plagueis* (2012)

By 25 ABY, enough was known that historian Voren Na'al was able to describe the events of the *Tales of the Jedi* era in a work commissioned by the New Republic Historical Council, [*The Essential Chronology*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Essential_Chronology). The second edition, [*The New Essential Chronology*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_New_Essential_Chronology_(in-universe)), was published in 36 ABY and included information about other Old Republic-era events, such as the Mandalorian Wars, the Jedi Civil War, and the Dark Wars, although the Great Galactic War and Cold War weren't mentioned. This book was apparently publicly distributed, since it was cited in published articles such as [*The Written Word*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Written_Word:_A_Brief_Introduction_to_the_Writing_Systems_of_Galactic_Basic).

### In Canon

It's not clear how much about the ancient Jedi and Sith is known by the time of the movies, or even whether any of the events of KOTOR are canon, but at the least, Revan was known to the Sith cultists on Exegol as an ancient Sith Lord, and was not known to the rest of the galaxy:

> Sith troopers are organized into legions, using the ancient definition of 5,000 soldiers. These are numerically identified, but also given the name of an ancient Sith Lord. **As this history was hidden from the rest of the galaxy, only the Sith Eternal cultists know the significance of these names.**
>
> [...]
>
> Notable Legions
>
> The 3rd: Revan Legion
>
> —*The Rise of Skywalker: The Visual Dictionary* (2019), emphasis added

### In non-canon

In the mobile game *Star Wars: Galaxy of Heroes*, the player plays the role of a cantina patron who plays simulated battles using holograms of various historical and legendary figures. This includes the full playable party from *Knights of the Old Republic*, plus Darth Malak. However, the game itself is non-canon.